# 0D type and n?0D randoms

Tags: kdb, k

In [A brief introduction to q and kdb+](https://code.kx.com/q/learn/brief-introduction/) there are several places with creation of time records with code like `0D00:01`.

And even random time generation technique using syntax:

```
n?0D0
fcn?0D00:00:20
```

I found `0D` mentioned only in q4m3 [2.5.2 Time Types](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/2_Basic_Data_Types_Atoms/#252-time-types) as optional.

Are there any references to this syntax on code.kx? And are there any other useful date/time random generators exist? I checked for capital-letters, - seems `0D` is the only one, see: `q)@[value;;::] each ("0",/:.Q.A)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first note that the `0D...` syntax is not specific to the rand operator. The prefix `0D` is needed when a type of a literal kdb would infer without it would be different from what you intended. For example:

```
q)type 08:09:10.123 / time
-19h
q)type 0D08:09:10.123 / timespan
-16h
```

The prefix is optional when a type can be inferred unambiguously; in case of timespan literals it's sufficient to supply more than 4 digits after the dot when using the `hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn` notation:

```
q)type 08:09:10.123 / time
-19h
q)type 08:09:10.1234 / still time
-19h
q)type 08:09:10.12345 / timespan
-16h
```

The `0D` notation is very handy when you need a timespan value but don't want to specify all the details down to nanoseconds. I think you will agree that `0D00:01` (1 minute) is easier to type and read than `00:01:00.000000000`.

Going back to your question, `0D0` is just a zero-valued timespan, the same as `00:00:00.00000000`. However, `?` treats it as if `1D0` (or `0D24:00:00.000000000`) was passed. I didn't see it documented anywhere on code.kx.com but if you think about it you'll agree that generating a timespan in the range [0; 24h) is such a common case that it definitely deserves a shortcut. And there you have it!